# Access global javascript variables using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JavaScript file and want to use it in an React Component.
The Script looks following:

```
function XMLtoJSON() {
    ....
} 
var xml2json = new XMLtoJSON();
```

And an `d.ts` File with

```
interface XMLtoJSON {
    ...
}
declare var xml2json: XMLtoJSON;
```

I tried to use `import './xml2json.js'` and the js-code is included in the generated js file, but the part that creates the variable xml2json is not executed.

I recive following error in the browser console `'xml2json' is undefined`

If it should be important, I use typescript and `.tsx`-files.
The Project was created with `create-react-app MyProject --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`

Comment: xml2json.js should export something in order to be used as import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too familiar with typescript for react but your exporting file should look something like this:

```
function XMLtoJSON() {
    ....
} 
var xml2json = new XMLtoJSON();
export xml2json;
```

and the importing file should have this somewhere in the file:

```
import { xml2json } from './xml2json';
```

Comment: adding exprt did nont helped somehow. I now rewritten the code as an typescript class which I exported.

Comment: ah I forgot it doesn't need `.js` at the end.